# Async Spring Boot using Kotlin not working

Tags: spring, asynchronous, callback, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to create a Spring Service that performs an operation asynchronously and returns a `ListenableFuture`. I want the failure callback to be triggered when the operation fails - my attempt to do this is to use `AsyncResult.forExecutionException` as seen below:

```
@Service
open class UserClientService {

    @Async
    fun fetchUser(email: String): ListenableFuture<User> {
        val uri = buildUri(email)
        val headers = buildHeaders()
        try {
            val result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity<Any>(headers), User::class.java)
            return AsyncResult.forValue(result.body)
        } catch (e: RestClientException) {
            return AsyncResult.forExecutionException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

The entry-point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
open class UserProxyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(UserProxyApplication::class.java, *args)
}
```

The Spring RestController implementation is as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
class UserController @Autowired constructor(
        val client: UserClientService
) {
    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
    fun getUser(@RequestParam(value = "email") email: String): DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<User>> {
        val result = DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<User>>(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10))
        client.fetchUser(email).addCallback(
                { success -> result.setResult(ResponseEntity.ok(success)) },
                { failure -> result.setResult(ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)) }
        )
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Problem** is that the failure callback in the `UserController` is never triggered when an exception is thrown in the `UserClientService` REST call. Instead, the success callback is triggered with `success` argument being `null`.

In Kotlin, I can check if success is null by using `success!!` - this throws an exception that then *does* trigger the failure callback with `failure` argument being the NPE.

**Question** is how can I trigger the failure callback in the `UserController` when an exception has occurred in the `UserClientService`?

**Update A** it seems that everything is executed on the same thread "http-nio-8080-exec-XXX" regardless of whether I use `@Async` or not -- see comments.

Comment: Have you tried just throwing your exception in your service class? That seems more logical than using forExecutionException. I don't know anything about Spring-Async though, so I could be totallly wrong here.

Comment: Then the exception propagates back to the caller - `UserController` where I can catch it. If that is the intended behaviour, what is the use-case for the failure callback that I *have* to implement?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure the function is actually being executed asynchronously? You could check what thread you're in with a debugger

Comment: I've tested with '@Async' and without. Tested with `Future` and `ListenableFuture` as return type. No difference, all executed on same "http-nio-8080-exec-XXX" thread. Followed the example here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all works if:

A) the method `fetchUser` is declared `open`, i.e. not final so that Spring can proxy the call

...or...

B) you create an interface `IUserClientService` and use that in the constructor of the `UserController`:

```
interface IUserClientService {
    fun fetchUser(email: String): ListenableFuture<User>
}
```

Now the `UserClientService` implements the interface:

```
@Service
open class UserClientService : IUserClientService {

    @Async
    override fun fetchUser(email: String): ListenableFuture<User> {
// ... rest as shown in question ...
```

And finally the `UserController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
class UserController @Autowired constructor(
    val client: IUserClientService
) {
    @RequestMapping(method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
    fun getUser(@RequestParam(value = "email") email: String): DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<User>> {
// ... rest as shown in question ...
```

Not sure if this is because I'm using Kotlin. The examples that I've seen don't require implementing an interface.

Comment: Should mention that doing a "clean" helps too.